# Check if field is blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Trying to create a workflow that will does action until field isn't empty. Is there a condition do until Field1 contains something? Can set it like this Field1 contains and then leave it blank? Will it understand?

Using PowerAutomate and Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In the Microsoft flow, add a step, click control, choose Do until.
[image]

2.Set condition as following picture shows.
[image]

Reference:
[How do i setup a check if sharepoint field is blank condition?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-do-i-setup-a-check-if-sharepoint-field-is-blank-condition/td-p/94886)